# SFINAE outside of overload resolution?

Tags: c++, sfinae

In his talk Modern Template Metaprogramming: A Compendium Part I, Walter Brown works his way to discussing the interaction of enable_if with SFINAE.

At approx 47:40 in the talk he is asked a question for which I can't quite match up his answer to the question being asked. However the crux of it sounds to be that he is saying SFINAE stands separate to overload resolution and just happens to be commonly used in overload resolution for functions.

The way I understand his answer is that he is also saying SFINAE has another use.

Outside of overload resolution where else can SFINAE be applied? Until hearing his answer to this question my understanding was that its *only* use was overload resolution.

EDIT: Talk is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY

Comment: To enable/disable partial template specializations?

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't think to use it for that. Disambiguation and partial ordering of any template specialization. Makes sense now that I think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable any template based on the parameters if you deem it appropriate.

For example, one could imagine that a matrix class should only be instantiated with arithmetic types.  That is, we want to allow matrices of reals and integers but not of strings, say.  You can do it like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
class Matrix
{
  // ...
};
```

Now, if a user does `Matrix<double> m {}` it will compile happily but a `Matrix<std::string>` would give a simple error message that such type is not defined.  This might help the user more than pages of error messages that some internals of the matrix class didn't yield valid code for `std::string` operands.

Another use case is selecting among partial specializations of templates.  This is maybe a silly example but it might give you an idea.  Suppose we have a template that takes two type parameters and want to specialize for the case where they both refer to the same type.  However, if the type is smaller than an `int`, the specialization is (for some obscure reason) worse than the primary template so we don't want it in that case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct X
{
  void
  operator()()
  {
    std::cout << "I'm the primary template." << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename T>
struct X<T, typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(T) >= sizeof(int)), T>::type>
{
  void
  operator()()
  {
    std::cout << "I'm the partial specialization." << std::endl;
  }
};

int
main()
{
  X<int, float> int_float {};  // primary template
  X<int, int> int_int {};      // partial specialization
  X<char, char> char_char {};  // primary template!
  int_float();
  int_int();
  char_char();
}
```

Output on my system:

```
I'm the primary template.
I'm the partial specialization.
I'm the primary template.
```

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation (and code snippets!). As soon as dyp replied to my question in the comments section it immediately occurred to me how it might be useful.